# Do C++ vector and Gtkmm work together perfectly?. Segmentation fault when getting values of vector<string> from gtkmm on_click method

Tags: c++, string, vector, gtkmm

I am in middle of creating treeview for my project using gtkmm and C++. 
What I want to do is to get variable properties from my **order** class. And I choose to use vector to store those properties so I get them easily by calling that method in the different class such as my **main_window** class. I can successfully get all values from other classes except **main_window** class showing segmentation fault.

To run my program:
1/ type "make" in terminal
2/ type "./mice" to run program
3/ click file->test. The program crashes

main_window.cpp class:

```
void Main_window::on_test_click() {
std::cout<< " On _test_clicked\n";
//auto add 1 order
controller.execute_cmd(99);
 //THE LINE BELOW IS NOT WORKING IN ON_TEST_CLICK
std::vector<std::string> record = controller.order_to_strings(0);
```

}

auto_add method from emporium. cpp

```
void Emporium::auto_add() {
  Order order0(1);
  add_order(&order0);  
  std::vector<std::string> record = order_to_strings(0);
  std::cout << "This is printing from emporium.cpp class" <<std::endl 
            << "Id:" << record[0] <<"State: "<< record[1]<<"Price:"<< record[2]<< std::endl;    
}
```

vector methods in emporium, order, controller classes.

```
std::vector<std::string> Controller::order_to_strings(int index) {
   emporium.order_to_strings(index);
}
std::vector<std::string> Emporium::order_to_strings(int index) { 
      return orders[index]->to_strings();
     }
std::vector<std::string> Order::to_strings(){
  std::vector<std::string> order;
  order.push_back(std::to_string(id_number));
  order.push_back(state.to_string());
  order.push_back(std::to_string(price));
  return order;
}
```

Error:

```
    *** Error in `./mice': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fa77a295000 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fa77d63a7e5]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fa77d64337a]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fa77d64753c]
    ./mice[0x406793]
    ./mice[0x4065cf]
    ./mice[0x40630a]
    ./mice[0x405eb7]
    ./mice(_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EED1Ev+0x35)[0x405b03]
 ......
```

This is my full version of my project. Test folder is my simplified version: https://github.com/dtn9797/MICE/tree/master/test

Answer (score 0):

In the method `auto_add()`, `Order` object is created, which is destroyed in the end of `auto_add()` method. However in mean time pointer to this object is added to vector `orders`. This pointer point to invalid data in memory outside `auto_add()` method. Accessing data behind this pointer give crash.

```
void Emporium::auto_add() {
  Order order0(1); //creating order0 local variable
  add_order(&order0);  //here pointer to something that will be destroyed soon is stored
  std::vector<std::string> record = order_to_strings(0);
  std::cout << "This is printing from emporium.cpp class" <<std::endl 
            << "Id:" << record[0] <<"State: "<< record[1]<<"Price:"<< record[2]<< std::endl;    
} //order0 local variable is destroyed here

void Emporium::add_order (Order* order) {
  orders.push_back(order);
}
```

One of possible solution to prevent crash you can create `Order` object like this:

```
void Emporium::auto_add() {
  add_order(new Order(1));
  std::vector<std::string> record = order_to_strings(0);
  std::cout << "This is printing from emporium.cpp class" <<std::endl 
            << "Id:" << record[0] <<"State: "<< record[1]<<"Price:"<< record[2]<< std::endl;    
}
```

But then for code correctness, remember to delete orders that are in `std::vector<Order*>  orders` in the `Emporium` class destructor.

Comment: So please tell  me what should I do to prevent this crash? Thanks! I have tried using Order *order0 = new Order (1); but it still doesn't work.